# After few minutes, car radio extremely heat up and right side of speakers stop working

Tags: electrical, audio

I have a car radio, like on images, radio goes 4-5 months without problems, and after 4-5 months I start having problem that after about 10-15 minutes of using the radio extremely heat up and right side of frond and back speakers stop working.

Do you have any solutions how to fix this ? Or I will must send it back to manufacture to repair it ?

Comment: You should check the speaker wires for any short circuits...

Comment: @Solar Mike It is doing only when is radio hot.